Can I use UICollectionView to render sub-sections within sections?
I've been digging around for quite a while (including an hour with ChatGPT) to try and figure out a way to achieve this UI using UICollectionView:

The iOS dev in me who has been doing this for 10+ years thinks that UICollectionView might not be capable of handling this kind of layout (sections within sections). But admittedly I am not up to speed on everything it can do. It looks like the compositional layout is designed to support something like this, but I can't figure out how to tie it all together. Ideally the section and sub-section headers would stick to the top as you scroll, but that isn't a deal breaker.
The existing code I am refactoring uses UICollectionView so I would prefer that out of convenience, but if there is a better way to achieve this I am open to it. TableViews inside of collectionView cells? A stackView of collectionViews? :grimacing: I am stumped.

Depends a bit on what you want to do with that layout... Assuming you are using a "circle" to represent a cell --  Will the circles be constant sizes - that is, always four (or fewer) to-a-row? Or, will you want n-number per row, based on device/view width? Will the circles be display-only? Or, do you need each circle to behave like a cell (selectable? drag-drop? etc)?

@donmag Good questions. The circles are cells and while the sizes are constant, the number that would fit would be dynamic per device. Each section could have a dynamic number of cells. We wouldn't need to drag and drop but we would need to respond to tap.

@Westley Please specify your minimum supported version of iOS (I want to understand what API is available to you), and also tell me if you are waiting for a comparative analysis of solutions or any “working” option will work for you

@Westley - to clarify... If you have, say, 11 cells and the phone is portrait orientation, you would have 3 rows: 4, 4, 3 ... but in landscape 11 cells might fit on 2 rows: 7, 4?

@PogosAnesyan min OS version is probably 17. Any working option will work! Even a point in the right direction would help. I'm stuck in the mud.

@DonMag portrait only! I'm not as concerned about the layout of the cells. Just fit as many as you can in the space available.

@Westley - take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/79098677/6257435 … it’s using variable-width “cells” but should be easily modified to fit your needs.

@Westley - did you get this worked out?
